# Pyspark S3 NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am trying to read S3 files from a small spark cluster I have running. I have the following jars installed:

```
"aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.975.jar"
"hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar"
```

And am using the following code:

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
import os

# initialise Spark session
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.jars", "aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.975.jar") \
    .config("spark.jars", "hadoop-aws-3.2.1.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.975,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws-3.2.1 pyspark-shell'

fp = "s3a://filepath/objects/"
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.parquet(fp)
```

However when I run this, I get the error `An error occurred while calling o62.parquet. : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException`

If I update `fp` to be `s3://...` I get the error `No FileSystem for scheme "s3"`

I have tried a few solutions on here, but nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: Hello, I have the same issue. I am running on Spark 3.3.0. I have the following hadoop-aws-3.3.0,jar and aws-java-sdk-1.12.344.jar added to the jars folder in my spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3 file. Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop 3.2.1 was built with AWS SDK 1.11.375; could be a version issue there or simply the aws SDK JAR didn't get on the classpath

I'd start with the "troubleshooting s3a" page in the Hadoop docs